# Any possible reason for getting IAE with `Unknown point starts with NULL` in Lottie for Android?

Tags: android, lottie, android-lottie

I am trying to integrate a `LottieAnimationView` in an Android project and get an `IllegalArgumentException` when inflating the xml layout.

I am trying to integrate a `LottieAnimationView` in an Android application, I have extracted the json from Lottie and integrated it in my `xml` as follows:

```
   <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/loading_animation"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/animation"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

I am getting the following `IllegalArgumentException`:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown point starts with NULL
                                                at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.JsonUtils.jsonToPoint(JsonUtils.java:55)
```

The same UI element works with another json lottie file, which makes me believe that there is a malformed json, but I cannot do something about it because it's the exported one.

Any idea would be greatly useful, thanks !